# How to use GetTcpTable2 function in Python?

Tags: python, tcp

GetTcpTable function helps me to get the IP/Port information of TCP connections from windows XP, but I also want to get the process id which related to them. How can I do?

I heve tried to change some parts of the sample code which helped me to use the GetTcpTable function. However, python returned me an error information: "function 'GetTcpTable2' not found".

Any one can show me a sample code of using GetTcpTable2 function in python? Thank you.

ps: the sample cold with GetTcpTable >> http://code.activestate.com/recipes/392572/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use this function on Windows XP. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Remarks

The GetTcpTable2 function is defined on Windows Vista and later.
```

Comment: I have changed another PC(windows 8) to run Python, but it returned me another error information. I hope to see a sample code in order to know how the GetTcpTable2 function works.

Comment: @Sunlit: that's probably better done as a separate question, otherwise this one will become really confusing.

Comment: Thanks, the new question is here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461884/how-does-gettcptable2-function-work-in-python, and I really hope you can help me.